# How to order by column from subquery which has index for sorting

Tags: postgresql

I use (PostgreSQL) 11.8. And I faced with this query and task about sort products by `createdAt, price and numberOfEntries` for owner table column (createdAt and price) I have index and I need to use it.

```
create index npdb_swedish_custom_index on products
                    using GIN(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', name||price||description||brand))


'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS created_desc_index ON products (created_at DESC NULLS LAST)'
'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS created_asc_index ON products (created_at ASC NULLS LAST)'
'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS price_desc_index ON products (price DESC NULLS LAST)'
'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS price_asc_index ON products (price ASC NULLS LAST)'
```

Figure out around the problem I try to join left the same table but, I did not found a solution, because when I add `ORDER BY sp.price ASC` I'm faced with

```
column "sp.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

my query

```
    SELECT                         
         array_agg(DISTINCT main_products_alias.id) AS ids
        FROM (

            SELECT                         
                    products_alias.id,
                    products_alias.group_identity,
                    products_alias.price,
                    products_alias.extras,
                    products_alias.created_at AS "createdAt"
                    ,COUNT(DISTINCT uip.id) as "numberOfEntries"
                    ,ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description||products_alias.brand), to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Barnvagnar|Solskydd')) AS rank


        FROM products products_alias 
        LEFT JOIN product_category cpt on cpt.product_id = products_alias.id
        LEFT JOIN user_ip_product uip on uip.products_id = products_alias.id               

        WHERE to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description||products_alias.brand) @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Barnvagnar|Solskydd')             



        GROUP BY products_alias.id
    ) AS main_products_alias

    LEFT JOIN products sp on sp.id = main_products_alias.id
    GROUP BY main_products_alias.group_identity
    ORDER BY sp.price ASC
```

Only thinkg what I made this is add to main select

```
(array_agg(DISTINCT main_products_alias.created_at))[1]::TIMESTAMP AS created_at_g,
```

and then `ORDER BY created_at_g DESC` but in this case my indexes not used :(

do some one some suggestion for that ?

Comment: If there can multiple prices per group, which one should be used to sort on?

Comment: @jjanes for sorting should using first price, like this `(array_agg(DISTINCT main_products_alias.price))[1]::INTEGER AS price`

Comment: Can you include the version of your query that runs but does not use the expected index? AFAICT the SQL in the question as of now is not runnable, the inner query would also have a GROUP BY issue since only .id is grouped, while group_identity, price, extras etc are in the SELECT list but not aggregated.